# Toggling on the reading pane in Outlook 2010 not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to display the reading pane in Outlook 2010. All the on-line instructions say to click the *view* tab, *view settings*, *other settings...*, toggle on the *right* or *bottom* radio buttons in the *Reading Pane* section of the dialog, and click OK and OK.

I am trying it, both selecting *right* and *bottom*, but the pane does not display. When I reopen the dialog, the *reading pane* radio button is toggled on as per my selection, but for whatever reason the setting isn't taking effect. Perhaps there is some sort of settings conflict I'm not aware of? Restarting Outlook doesn't help.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and found the answer on another forum. I know this is an old thread, but I figured I'd post the answer anyway.

In Outlook, go to **Tools**, and then click on **Trust Center**.

On the left menu pane, select **Add-ins**

On the bottom, there is a drop down window, select **Disabled Items** and click Go.

You should see **reading pane** (or similar wording), select it, click **Enable**, and then **Close**. Shut down Outlook, restart, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been doing without ever since posting this. It's a disabled addon...

Comment: Just to addon (pun intended) to the answer, the steps to enable the feature are slightly different for Outlook 2010:  Home->Options->Add-Ins-> Manage: Disabled Items (it's at the bottom of the addins screen). After you've enabled the addin (or if it was already enabled) follow @Avni 's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue today. I couldn't get the reading pane to show from within the View settings. But I was able to get it to show using the Reading Pane command on the ribbon. Found the answer [here](http://www.justanswer.com/computer/5zsui-restore-reading-pane-outlook.html).

1. First close Outlook completely and re-open
2. Then click on View tab
3. Then find the Reading Pane command and click "Bottom" or "Right" on the drop down

Comment: This is correct but did not work for me, until I followed the excepted answer. I'd mark this up but do not have rights to do so.

Comment: excepted = accepted

Answer (score -1):

This works in 2010 version.
Go to File->Options->Add-Ins tab. 
On the bottom of the page select 'Disabled Items' from the Manage drop down list. Click Go. Then enable the Reading pane. Restart Outlook it works.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.